# Multiple router-outlet, named router-outlet doesn't work

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I am trying to get multiple router-outlet working with different Component on the same path, however, the following code doesn't work.

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'products', component: ProductComponent},
{ path: 'products', component: ProductHeaderComponent, outlet: 'header-route' },
{ path: 'products', component: ProductFooterComponent, outlet: 'footer-route' }
];
```

Html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>//Primary Outlet
<router-outlet name="header-route"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="footer-route"></router-outlet>
```

Primary Outlet works.

Named Outlets, header-route and footer-route does not work.

Comment: Can you show your code for how you're trying to navigate to those components. Are you using routerlinks or doing it programmatically in your component code?

Comment: I am testing it by navigating to via the browser url. 
    http://localhost:4200/products

Comment: I see. Would you show the path you're entering into the URL to attempt to navigate to those routes?

Comment: Oh geez, I totally overlooked that you have the exact same path to your different components. That is definitely not going to work either. You need to have a unique path to each component. They all can't have `path: 'products'` as their path.

Comment: I've got to run off for a bit. Take a look at this [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-named-outlet). Hopefully that helps for now, if not I will check back later. Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to have a different header and footer dependent based on the route/path. Doing it like how you have would make a not very clean url path and not very effective for me

Comment: Named router outlets are populated based on the portion of the route defined within the parens `(header-route: products)`. If you don't want those parens in your URL, then you'll need to use another technique that does not use named router outlets.

Comment: If you want a different header/footer depending on the routed component, why not put the header/footer in the routed component's template instead of in the primary template?

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple router outlet and access secondary router url by using (outletname: route) Example:

```
localhost:4200/loginpage(header-route: products)
```

Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/secondary-router-outlet)